# WCF IsRequired Attribute dilemma

Tags: wcf

For a customer we are developing some WCF webservices. Our message contracts are defined by using  DataContract and DataMember attributes on top of our classes and their properties.
The DataMember attribute has some extra properties that allows us to add some extra rules. For example if a property should always be available, we use (IsRequired=true); to indicate this. These rules are checked when a message is received or send.

```
[DataContract]
public class TestClass      
{  
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]  
    public int RequiredValue { get; set; }      
}
```

However during our test we noticed that it doesn’t work, because at client side the RequiredValueField is initialized by null, so with some reading i found this property, EmitDefaultValue=false, so by using both, i get the desired result

```
[DataContract]  
public class TestClass  
{  
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue=false)]  
        public int RequiredValue { get; set; }  
}
```

but suppose, if some client initialize `RequiredValue = 0` and then call service method, it gives error again. **So how do free my APIusers with an option that they can pass any thing in this member including zero, but when they omit then only it should give error** ?

Answer (score 2):

1. You have not mentioned what your "desired" result is. I mean what you are trying to achieve.
2. Do you know that MS does not recommend setting `EmitDefaultValue` to `false` unless it's absolutely necessary? Please read last section of [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347792.aspx) to know the reason.
3. When you set `EmitDefaultValue` to `false`, the WSDL generated for your service has some annotations which are understood by WCF only. i.e. by doing so, you may restrict interoprability of your service. Is that your requirement?

**Solution to your problem:**

Make your DataMember "RequiredValue" a nullable int.

```
[DataMember(IsRequired = true,EmitDefaultValue=false)]  
    public int? RequiredValue { get; set; }
```

By doing so, the default value of the `RequiredValue` data member will be `null` and you will be able to set zero (0) without any problem.